# Proposed candidate for migration to programmers.se

Tags: discussion, migration

[What are five things you hate about your favorite language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282329/what-are-five-things-you-hate-about-your-favorite-language)

The above strikes me as in the zone of things that make more sense there than on SO. There is an attempt to delete it underway, though it will take an awfully large number of deletors.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't migrate.

There are several possible duplicates already on the site including this most obvious one:

[What syntax element do you hate most in a programming language you use frequently?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/501/what-syntax-element-do-you-hate-most-in-a-programming-language-you-use-frequently)

It's also not really the sort of question we want on Programmers' anyway. The Programmers' one was asked back in September when the rules were looser than they are now. It's also CW.

Also it's a **really old** (like 2008) question. There's no benefit to either the question or Programmers' in having it migrated.

Comment: Fair enough. That raises the counter-question: is the 'how many delete votes' algorithm really doing useful work here?

Comment: @Rosinante - well it depends on your point of view ;) It *was* designed to protect old, popular but now less welcome questions from deletion.

Comment: you were?

Comment: @Do'h. "It was" ;)

Comment: I figured as much, it was just too tempting of a rimshot.